# What assembly is ValidationRule in?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, assemblies

I'm trying to build a validation rule for a C# WPF application by creating a class that implements ValidationRule. My problem is that I can't find the System.Windows.Controls assembly which - acconding to the documentation - contains it. Does anybody know the right assembly in the 3.5 runtime ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Namespace:**  System.Windows.Controls
>   **Assembly:** PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) is your friend. (Namespace != assembly)

Comment: Just waiting for the 10m timeout ... ;)